# Existence of function $f^{s}=tn$ for fix s,t natural numbers and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Problem:Consider positive integers $s,t$. Does there exist a function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $\mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{s}(n)=tn$ for all $n$ where

$f^{s}(n)=f(f(f(..f(n))))\text{(s 
compositions of f)}$

So here is My attempt, I want some one to check.

$\textbf{Solution:}$

Easy to note $f$ must be bijective

$\textbf{Case 1:}$ Suppose there exist a fixed point then $t=1$ (forced)

$\textbf{Case 2:}$ Else if there must be a cycle for $f(1),f^{2}(1),....f^{k}(1)=1$ for some postive integer $k$ say that $k$ is least such then it is easy to note $f^{ks}(1)=1$ but $f^{s}(n)=tn$ thus $f^{s+r}(n)=tf^{r}(n)$ for all non-negative integer $r$ thus we have $t|f^{d}(n)$ for all $n\geq 1$ and for all $d\geq s$ hence choosing $d=ks$ and $n=1$  we have $t|1$ then $t=1$!!!

Hence in both case $t=1$ this we need to look $f^{s}(n)=n$ but then we can easy choose $f(x)=x$

$\textbf{Conclusion:}$

$f(x)=x$ is such function whenever $t=1$ unless If $t>1$ we cannot have Case 1 and 2 to be true.

Comment: Assumptions imply that $f^s$ is "onto", hence $n\mapsto tn$ is "onto" . Thus $t=1.$ Let $f(n)=n+1$ if $n$ is not divisible by $s$ and $f(is)=is-s+1.$ Then $f^s(n)=n$ So $f(n)=n$ is not the only possibility.

Comment: $f(n)=n+1$ is not a suitable choice for this question as it misses "1" but we can prove "f" is bijective.

Comment: Read the definition of $f$ in my comment carefully. The value $f(n)$ depends on the divisibility of $n$ by $s.$

Comment: Okay Sir, I got it,

Comment: Is my proof $t=1$ correct I mean $t=1$ is forced by problem only right?

Comment: Since the question ask does there exist I choose $f(n)=n$  with $t=1$ which is forced by problem statement but Your construction is indeed nice!!! I didn't understand your point initially but now I get it!!! Nice !!

Comment: Thanks. Your proof about $t=1$ is correct, but I prefer mine from my first comment. I was just curious if other example exist for a given $s.$ Please do not call me Sir, just Ryszard.

Comment: I don't understand why $f$ should be onto. For instance if $s=2$ and $t=25$, you can take $f(n)=5n$.